# upload a picture in safari on a real device with webdriverio & browserstack javascript

Tags: webdriver-io, browserstack

I am facing an issue with an automate test case (webdriverIO with a Real Device on Browserstack, Iphone 11 Safari capabilities)

in the test case I am going to my website and there is an upload picture button, I want to upload an image to verify the file is being uploaded using a web browser on a mobile device.

I have an error message

> webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to Error: The object is in an invalid state.

any help would be great !
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9120#issuecomment-326139289, I don't think there is a way to upload files on mobile browsers.

Also, you can refer to https://gitter.im/webdriverio/webdriverio?at=5d8df5f066c8b45122275187

https://gitter.im/webdriverio/webdriverio?at=5d5c6b33c508da44c352b67f

for generic webdriverio errors.

Comment: Hello thanks for your help !

indeed it seems difficult, but this issue was from 30 Aug 2017 ... I guess there is some new possibilities since 2017 right ?

I found this link but I am unable to write it in wdio JS

https://www.itdaan.com/tw/303c9326818dd658988ed6324398614e

do you think it could work ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share some more information? Maybe the code you are using where you are trying to upload the picture?

Browserstack offers a couple of solutions for this. If you want to use your own image you can choose to use the browserstack.uploadMedia capability. You can put this capability into your config file which ensures that the images you want to use is uploaded to the device you want to test before you run the test. You then will only have to navigate to the folder to access the image.

Browserstack also offers images in the "Recent" folder. Can you not navigate to there and select an image from there?

You can find some more information about this here https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/advanced-features/test-with-sample-data#iOS